# Bootstrap 3.2.0 modal and remote content not visible close button

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I use the bootstrap 3.2.0 modal dialog to display the contents of the remote, only the contents completely fills the modal window and close button in the header is not visible.

This is my code:

```
  <a  href="#" data-remote="<?php echo dynamic url ?> #fragment" data-toggle="modal"     data-target="#myModal"></a>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Event</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Loading...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

```
  $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal','.modal',function(){ $(this).removeData('bs.modal');});
```

Comment: This should be working. Is this online anywhere? I would check your css (use dev tools) to find out if the modal-header is being hidden or set to display:none.

Comment: I do not use any css for modal. I forgot to mention that modal footer also not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I paste your code in [here](http://jsbin.com/nufaka/1/)

So it hasn't any problems.I think this page in `data-remote="<?php echo dynamic url ?>` has error => modal can't load all then button close and modal-footer haven't loaded yet.

Comment: You have not correctly understood. Modality used for remote capture contents of the container with ID #fragment.